# Progress and progress all only called twice of JQuery file upload

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I am using Jquery file upload basic. To show progress bar I am using 'fileuploadprogressall' event binding

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload().bind('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                console.log(data.loaded +" "+data.total+"  "+progress);
                $('#progress').css('visibility','visible');
                $('#progress .bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
```

It works fine in FF and Chrome and shows the progress. But in IE11 to 9, it is called only two times, one with 0% and another one with 100%. 
So the progress bar hides even before the file is actually loaded. 
Below is the output of a file with size

```
DATA loaded  total data   percentage
271          128584       0 
128584       128584       100
```

Can someone please help to figure out why it is being called only twice?

Comment: IE 10 is apparently the first to support HTML5's `progress` event, so you won't get it working in IE9 without a flash fallback (which I believe is what gmail uses as a fallback, or at least used to). As for why it doesn't work in 10 and 11, are you sure it's not running in compatibility mode?

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support#upload-progress

Comment: On the example page of Jquery-file-upload, it seems to work on IE 8 also. Anything else should also be done?